# Convert to links all the ulrs contained into a text

Tags: php, regex

I have a form with a textarea where a user can write anything, included urls. I'm trying to convert those urls into html links.

I can do that until there is only 1 url, but when there are more than 1 I have a problem to manage them.

To convert 1 url I use this code

```
$reg_ex_url = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";

if( preg_match($reg_ex_url, $text, $url) ) {
    $text = preg_replace($reg_ex_url, "<a href='".$url[0]."'>".$url[0]."</a> ", $text);
}
```

Of course I suppose I'll have to use preg_match_all(), but then how do I loop on the results to convert each single url?

I forgot to add my try with preg_match_all()

```
if( preg_match_all($reg_ex_url, $text, $urls) ) {
    foreach($urls[0] as $url) {
        $text = str_replace($url,'<a href="'.$url.'">'.$url.'</a>',$text);
    }
}
```

This works, but it seems highly unefficient to me, if a user writes many links, the loop takes many iterations to modify 1 url each time.

New version, but I'm yet not sure that it is the best one

```
if( preg_match_all($reg_ex_url, $text, $urls) ) {
    foreach( $urls[0] as $url ) {
        $sub[] = '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$url.'</a>';
    }

    $text = str_replace($urls[0],$sub,$text);
}
```

Comment: You should escape the URLs before including them in your HTML. If you use that piece of code you’ll be vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Comment: Sure I know that, but I couldn't write all the code here, I just showed what's needed to understand my problem.

Comment: I am not sure where you see the performance issue. There is no magic simultaneous substitution transforming all matches at once. Even if the iteration is hidden from the source code, it will be there (ie. substitutions will be applied 1-by-1). Having said this, have a look at [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

Comment: I see. So I think that the best structure is the one used in the first try with preg_match_all(), in that case there is only one loop, the last has 2 loops, my foreach and another one hidden into str_replace.

Comment: You have an issue in your url pattern as you are too restrictive with your toplevel domain: there are TLDs with more than 3 chars ( eg.`.info` ). You also do not cater for numeric ips. Btw,the trailing pattern `(\/\S*)?` is optional,so it can be dropped from the regex (unless you expect urls in the query strings which you wish to skip; though they should be properly escaped,not matching your regex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an non capturing group `(:` for this part `(http|https|ftp|ftps)`:

[`(?:http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?`](https://regex101.com/r/U07EZm/1/)

Using [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) might also be an option:

```
$reg_ex_url = "/(?:http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
$text = "This is http://www.test.nowhere, and this is http://www.test2.nowhere";

$output = preg_replace_callback($reg_ex_url,
    function($matches) {
    $match = $matches[0];
        return "<a href='".$match."'>".$match."</a> ";    
    }, $text);

echo $output;
```

<kbd>[**Online php demo**](https://3v4l.org/hIJp9)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

using preg_replace and backreferences

```
$reg_ex_url = "/((?:http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(?:\/\S*)?)/";
$text = preg_replace($reg_ex_url,'<a href="\1">\1</a>',$text);
```

groups `(..)` have been replaced with non-capturing groups `(?:..)` and the surronding group is added so that `\1` references the first group (whole match)

otherwise as `\0` can be used to reference the whole match, with original regex

```
$text = preg_replace($reg_ex_url,'<a href="\0">\0</a>',$text);
```